# Get Exceptions: 1 when running nodetool info?

Tags: exception, cassandra

When running nodetool info in Cassandra get below output:

```
----------


Gossip active    : true
Thrift active    : true
Load             : 423.25 GB
Generation No    : 1371022989
Uptime (seconds) : 514706
Heap Memory (MB) : 4148.05 / 7987.25
Data Center      : datacenter1
Rack             : rack1
Exceptions       : 1


----------
```

**please note : Exceptions       : 1**
would like to know exactly what it means and how to resolve (if there is any need to resolve)

Answer (score 3):

The exceptions count gets incremented when there is an uncaught exception in the Cassandra daemon.  When this happens it also logs the error like this:

logger.error("Exception in thread {}", t, e);

So to see what the actual error was, you'd need to check the Cassandra log file.

A count of 1 is not particularly worrisome since it may have just been a glitch of some kind.  If it happens consistently or more frequently, then it would be more concerning.